# What happens when operator new returns address in this code "new T"?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

```
class T{
public:
    T(){}
};

int main ()
{
  T *t = new T; //line 8

}
```

I mean how the code looks like before enter to constructor? For example, in line 8 operator new returns address, and then the code looks like `T *t = T 0x0FF00` , because it's like object definition and can't be like `0x0FF00 T`. So if it's true, how this address which returns by operator new, stands after type T, despites the fact that operator new returns it before?

Comment: Sorry, but I read your posting three times and I still don't understand what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.  Could you edit your question to clarify what you're talking about?

Comment: What do you mean "code looks like `T *t = T 0x0FF00`"?

Comment: In this code `new T` operator new returns address and then constructor must create object at this address. So how constructor gets this address and think that this address is like object name?

Comment: @mzarb That still makes no sense, I'm afraid. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T *t = new T;
//     ^^^^^
```

This is a declaration of `t` of type `T*`. It is being initialized by the expression after the `=`. The entire `new T` part is the *new-expression* in this initializer.

The *new-expression* causes memory to be allocated for an object of type `T` and then that object is constructed in that space. The *new-expression* returns a pointer to that object. That is, after the *new-expression* has been evaluated, the line now looks like:

```
T *t = returned_pointer;
```

I assume you're using `0x0FF00` as an example memory address - in which case, you can imagine the line has become:

```
T *t = 0x0FF00; // Note: this wouldn't actually compile because 0x0FF00 is an integer literal
```

The pointer `t` is now initialized with that memory address.

You might be confused by what exactly a *new-expression* does. It has these two steps:

1. It calls the appropriate allocation function (typically `operator new`), passing the size of the memory it needs to store an object of type `T`. `operator new` allocates that memory and returns an address that points at that location.
2. It then initializes an object of type `T` in that space.